# Docker exec. How to use shell-commands in container without entering?

Tags: docker

Can someone explain me, how can I use sh-commands inside container without enter that container?

I use a shell script at my host. I want this shell-script to enter one of my container and then curl post to another container through overall network. So, my problem is that when i tring to do something like:

```
docker exec -ti nodejs sh "curl -X POST \
  http://tgbot:3017/deploy \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d 'message=Prod has been updated!'"
```

I have in console:

```
sh: 0: Can't open curl -X POST   http://tgbot:3017/   -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'   -H 'cache-control: no-cache'   -d 'message=Prod has been updated!'
```

failed to resize tty, using default size

Or mayby I can curl into docker network right from host somehow?

Comment: Your main container command can be a shell script, or it's common to set an image's default entrypoint to a shell script that runs a series of `sh` commands ending in `exec "$@"` to run the command.  Is there a specific problem you're encountering; can you give an example of a setup that doesn't work?

Comment: @David Maze I have updated the question

Comment: Your `sh` command is missing a `-c` option; but you don't really need that, you can just `docker exec nodejs curl http://tgbot:3017/deploy ...`.  A better option is probably to publish a port for the `tgbot` container so you can connect directly from the host (without needing the root-equivalent permissions that `docker exec` requires).

Comment: @David Maze ok, I'll use the second one. Thx a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can just use Docker exec command on the host machine.
`docker exec -it <container name> <command>`